# How to combine this regex into one

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract the last word of a string but ignoring any extension it may have 
e.g. `amazon_uk` instead of `amazon_uk.gif`

The following code extracts the word from the string using 2 preg_match functions, I want to be able to do the same thing in 1 preg_match, how can I do this?

**php code**

```
$str = 'http://i.example.com/about/bs/logo_borderless/amazon_uk.gif';

preg_match('/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/', $str, $matches);
preg_match('/^[^.]+(?=.)/', $matches[0], $matches2);
$website = $matches2[0];
```

**output**

```
amazon_uk
```

Comment: Is it always going to be that format (i.e. an URI)?

Comment: There's something to be said for using `parse_url()` in these situations, to at least do the first pass of parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match( '#/([^./]+)\.[^./]+$#si', $str, $matches );
```

**Here's what it's doing...**

```
/
```

match a forward slash

```
([^./]+)
```

Then one or more of neither a period or forward slash. This is the bit we're matching.

```
\.
```

Then a period

```
[^./]+
```

Then one or more of neither a period or forward slash again.

```
$
```

Then the end of the string

---

You asked about a regex, so that's above. But here's what I'd actually do...

```
$url = 'http://i.example.com/about/bs/logo_borderless/amazon_uk.gif';
$output = str_replace( array('.gif','.jpg','.png'), '', basename($url) );
```

**[Basename](http://php.net/basename)**'s something I use all the time - very handy.

Comment: Isn't that why you asked the question?

Answer (score 2):

Because it will always be in the format you specified (per a comment), you can also use a combination of `substr()` and `strpos()` (and `strrpos()`) to get the text as opposed to regex:

```
// get the filename after the last slash
$file = substr($str, strrpos($str, '/') + 1);
// get the text before the extension
$website = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, '.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/\/([\w]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,3})$/', $str, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, I want to get the string after the last forward slash and before the .gif extension what this return is `/amazon_uk.gif`

Comment: it returns *amazon_uk* for me.
try ignoring the 2nd line and have a look at `var_dump($matches)`

Answer (score 0):

A non-greedy search plus a optional match on the extension should do the trick:

```
preg_match('/([^\.\/]+?)(?:\.\w*)?$/', $str, $matches);
$website = $matches[1];
```